# search database php pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some php experience but i've been working on a search feature and cant figure out a way to do my task without a loop.

The situation:
someone will enter an address in a form (example 123 main st.)

I have a database with street names in it (over 200)

```
streetID - streetName
1        - Random Drive
2        - Curvy Crescent
3        - Main Street
4        - Station Main Lane
etc..
```

Does mysql have a built in function that could compare "123 main st." and return the street id?

Comment: compare 123 main st with what ? explain more.

Comment: PDO's job is to provide a generic-ish interface between PHP and a database. It is not, never has been, and never will be, PDO's job to "search" the database for you. That's up to YOU, and the queries you pass in to PDO, which simply get passed in to the database.

Comment: sorry. find the streetID from the most probably match

Comment: What is in this case the most probably match? '3: Main Street'?

Comment: correct. 3.
i meant mysql query.

Comment: You're going to have to do some legwork on this one...parse the input and do a few "select where like"s

Answer (score 0):

> Does PDO have a built in function

No. PDO is just a driver that sends your query to database and returns results back. It does no data manipulation of its own.

You have to use fulltext search feature of mysql, or some dedicated search engine like Sphinx.

Comment: I think he is looking at PDO as it was some kind of ORM.

Comment: no i meant sql query. my brains just mush from trying to figure this out